# word is not closing via vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

when i open word, only UserForm1 is opened and word view is in the background. So far it works. When I close UserForm1, word also closes, all good but in the background in task manager microsoft word is still open and I don't want that. This means that when I close UserForm1, the complete word document should also be closed as normal.

my code:

```
Sub AutoOpen()

    Application.Visible = False

    UserForm1.Hide
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer, appWord As Object)

    If CloseMode = vbFormCode Then
        ThisDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
        appWord.Quit
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `UserForm_QueryClose` has no `appWord`-parameter?!  Try to use `Application.quit`

Comment: @FunThomas already tried as well, didnt work.

Comment: Are you sure that your Query-Close is triggered at all? The routine doesn't match what VBA expects (there is no third parameter) and I guess it is not called. Use the debugger to check (set a breakpoint into the routine)

Comment: which is the module you have your code? I suppose open should be in the document's module, while close in the form's module

Comment: @MátéJuhász worked with the Answer from Faneduru. But if I have another word doc. which is already open and if i open my word doc with macro. It closes both docs. But i just want to close the vba doc

Comment: got it, just replaced appWord.Quit with ThisDocument.close

Comment: Yes, but you need to check how many documents are open (documents.count). If > 1 then close the document...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try `UserForm_Terminate` event in the next way:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
   Dim appWord As Object
   Set appWord = Application
   ThisDocument.Save
   appWord.Quit
End Sub
```

If the document having the form is closed, the part of the code quitting the application is not accesibile, anymore. In this way, the event is able to quit Application, which closes the workbook (without asking about saving it)...

Comment: FaneDuru and @Máté Juhász combined both infos and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Next problem: When I have another Word doc. its closing as well if I run the vba.

Comment: got it, just replaced appWord.Quit with ThisDocument.close